# Копирование данных thread_local-переменной для новых потоков

Tags: c++, многопоточность, tls, global-variables, threading

Всем привет. Мне потребовалось создать уникальный для разных потоков глобальный контейнер. Обратил внимание на thread_local. Однако существует проблема: мне необходимо, чтобы в новом потоке оставались элементы контейнера, добавленные в main потоке, а с thread_local я получаю пустой контейнер в новом потоке. Как мне сохранить данные из main потока для нового потока, чтобы дальше он мог с ними работать?

Приведу пример с глобальной переменной.

Имеем глобальную переменную `thread_local int i = 0;`, далее в main потоке сделали, к примеру, `i = 5;`
Затем создали новый поток. Мне необходимо, чтобы в этом новом потоке `i == 5`,
а не `i == 0`.

При этом, ни изменения этой переменной из main, ни из нового потока не должны влиять друг на друга (что и обеспечит thread_local)

Comment: Передавать как аргумент и копировать в свою переменную?

Comment: К сожалению, этот вариант не подходит. Нужно решение, которое не будет менять логику создания потоков.

Comment: сделайте обычную ссылку `int & i_main = i;` и после создания потока этот новый поток должен сам обновить переменную `i = i_main ;`

Comment: Идею понял. Но такое решение тоже не подходит. Опять-таки, необходимо обходить все места, где создаются потоки и делать это присваивание, что заставляет влезать в логику создания потоков. Необходимо решение именно со стороны контейнера (в моем примере переменной). Возможно, можно реализовать некий синглтон отдельный для каждого потока, который, при первом вызове, сделает это присваивание сам. Буду думать)

Comment: В С++26 думают добавить [`thread_local_inherit`](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2022/p2633r0.html), который это и делает. Раз думают, значит есть какой-то способ. Я бы поискал в pthread.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать это несложно, однако требует использования динамической инициализации:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int global{};
thread_local int threaded{global};

void worker()
{
    ::std::cout << threaded;
}

int main()
{
    global = 5;
    threaded = global;
    ::std::thread{&worker}.join();
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:18,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Cthread%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aint+global%7B%7D%3B%0Athread_local+int+threaded%7Bglobal%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+worker()%0A%7B%0A++++::std::cout+%3C%3C+threaded%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++global+%3D+5%3B%0A++++threaded+%3D+global%3B%0A++++::std::thread%7B%26worker%7D.join()%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g131,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-pthread%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)